# Why isn't all HTML scraped when in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm looking to find a `ul` tag from a page using:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(<chromedriver path>, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles")
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
dropdown = soup.find("ul", class_="dropdown")
```

`dropdown` ends up being `None` because not all the HTML is scraped.

However, if I remove the `headless` option then all the HTML is scraped and I have a result for `dropdown`.

Why does this happen and is there some way of running in headless and still scraping all the HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried it. This happens when we use chrome(I don't know why). I tested it by using firefox and it was successful. Note: `headless` should be `--headless`

Answer (score 1):

If you print that html (returned by headless mode) to a file and open in a browser you will see:

[image]

So your interaction is blocked by a CAPTCHA. Why headless mode in chrome is blocked but regular is not? No idea, this is how their identification algorithms work.

Answer (score 1):

Headless runs a different user agent using the below fixed the error due to bot detection. Also adding window size makes finding elements a little bit safer.

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1866.237 Safari/537.36"
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={agent}')
```